# Stream within a Stream using two list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am having 2 Employee List. One List contains the name and employeeId and the second List contains employeeId and mobile number. employee id is the primary key.
The requirement is to get the List which contains the id, Name, and mobile no using streaming.

```
public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Employee emp1 = new Employee(101, "Shiv1");
        Employee emp2 = new Employee(102, "Shiv2");
        Employee emp3 = new Employee(103, "Shiv3");
        Employee emp4 = new Employee(104, "Shiv4");

        Employee emp5 = new Employee(101, 00001);
        Employee emp6 = new Employee(101, 00002);
        Employee emp7 = new Employee(101, 00003);
        Employee emp8 = new Employee(101, 00004);

        List<Employee> employeeNameList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        employeeNameList.add(emp1);
        employeeNameList.add(emp2);
        employeeNameList.add(emp3);
        employeeNameList.add(emp4);

        List<Employee> employeeMobileList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        employeeMobileList.add(emp5);
        employeeMobileList.add(emp6);
        employeeMobileList.add(emp7);
        employeeMobileList.add(emp8);

        employeeNameList.stream()
            .filter(item -> item.getId() == 3)
            .map(i -> i.setMobileNo(9089));
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is the result of the input you've provided expected to be?

Comment: What is your question?  Is there a compiler error?  An exception?  Incorrect output?  Please edit your question so it's clear what's going wrong.

Comment: You can use a `Map<id, employee>` with one list and loop over the other list.

Comment: Do you mean like a `FULL OUTER JOIN` in SQL, where every object in list 1 with an given id is cross-joined with every object in list 2 with the same id, even if one of the lists don't have an object? I.e. you want result to be `[[101, "Shiv1", 00001], [101, "Shiv1", 00002], [101, "Shiv1", 00003], [101, "Shiv1", 00004], [102, "Shiv2", null], [103, "Shiv3", null], [104, "Shiv4", null]`?

Comment: Output will be one employeeList containing records : emp1(101,"shiv1",00001),emp2(102,"shiv2",00002) like this

Comment: Are the IDs in the second list typos? Shouldn't they be 101, 102, 103 etc as well? If so, you are basically looking for a "join" operation, right?

Comment: output is coming as Employee [id=101, name=Shiv1, mobileNo=1]
Employee [id=101, name=Shiv1, mobileNo=2]
Employee [id=101, name=Shiv1, mobileNo=3]
Employee [id=101, name=Shiv1, mobileNo=4].... it is not correct as output provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can create a mapping of the `empId` to their `name` using the first list.

   ```
   Map<Integer, String> empIdToName = employeeNameList.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getId, Employee::getName, (a, b) -> a));
   ```
2. Use such a mapping to create the objects further while iterating through the second and looking up this map, such as:

   ```
   List<Employee> employees = employeeMobileList.stream()
           .filter(item -> empIdToName.containsKey(item.getId()))
           .map(i -> new Employee(i.getId(), empIdToName.get(i.getId()), i.getMobileNo()))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```

Comment: Note: This is based on the output in the comment which portrays there are possible mistyped inputs in the question and the output you seek is a merge of two lists to form employee objects with complete details.

Comment: output is coming as Employee [id=101, name=Shiv1, mobileNo=1]
Employee [id=101, name=Shiv1, mobileNo=2]
Employee [id=101, name=Shiv1, mobileNo=3]
Employee [id=101, name=Shiv1, mobileNo=4].... it is not correct as output provided. it must be like Employee [id=101, name=Shiv1, mobileNo=1]
Employee [id=102, name=Shiv2, mobileNo=2]
Employee [id=103, name=Shiv3, mobileNo=3]
Employee [id=104, name=Shiv4, mobileNo=4]

Comment: @imdon As I said in the note as well, it really matters what your input is. With the current input, how can you expect `[id=102, name=Shiv2, mobileNo=2]` in the output?